# How can I refactor this code to be less repetitive?

Tags: javascript, html, refactoring

I am fairly new to Javascript and am looking at how to be more efficient. All I need to do is to determine the height of two sets of divs including their margins and then apply this height to the overall container. This has to be applied to two separate divs. I have essentially written the code twice rather than use a function such as forEach (which I'm not sure if even applicable here). I'm sure there is a way to cut this down significantly but I can't seem to find the solution.

```js
  var container = document.querySelectorAll('#agent_1, #agent_2');
  var content = document.querySelectorAll('#content_1, #content_2');
  // Agent 1 divs
  var topInclusiveA1 
    = content[0].children[0].offsetHeight
    + content[0].children[1].offsetHeight
    + parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(content[0].children[0], null).getPropertyValue('margin-bottom'))
    + parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(content[0].children[1], null).getPropertyValue('margin-bottom'));
  var bottomInclusiveA1 
    = content[0].children[2].offsetHeight
    + content[0].children[3].offsetHeight
    + parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(content[0].children[2], null).getPropertyValue('margin-bottom'))
    + parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(content[0].children[3], null).getPropertyValue('margin-bottom'));
  // Agent 2 divs
  var topInclusiveA2 
    = content[1].children[0].offsetHeight
    + content[1].children[1].offsetHeight
    + parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(content[1].children[0], null).getPropertyValue('margin-bottom'))
    + parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(content[1].children[1], null).getPropertyValue('margin-bottom'));
  var bottomInclusiveA2 
    = content[1].children[2].offsetHeight
    + content[1].children[3].offsetHeight
    + parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(content[1].children[2], null).getPropertyValue('margin-bottom'))
    + parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(content[1].children[3], null).getPropertyValue('margin-bottom'))


  // AGENT 1
  // Set max height to Div 1 + 2
  content[0].style.maxHeight = topInclusiveA1 + 'px';

  // Functions when hovered
  function mouseOverA1(){
    content[0].style.maxHeight = (topInclusiveA1 + bottomInclusiveA1) + 'px';
  };
  function mouseOutA1(){
    content[0].style.maxHeight = topInclusiveA1 + 'px';
  };

  // AGENT 2
  // Set max height to div 0 + 1
  content[1].style.maxHeight = topInclusiveA2 + 'px';

  // Functions when hovered
  function mouseOverA2(){
    content[1].style.maxHeight = (topInclusiveA2 + bottomInclusiveA2) + 'px';
  };
  function mouseOutA2(){
    content[1].style.maxHeight = topInclusiveA2 + 'px';
  };

  // Add event listeners
  container[0].addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOverA1);
  container[0].addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOutA1);
  container[1].addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOverA2);
  container[1].addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOutA2);
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid agent-bg">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row pt-5 pb-5">
          <div id="agent_1" class="col-sm-4 p-0 mr-5 agent">
            <div class="agent-photo">
              <img src="img/agent.jpg">
            </div>
            <div id="content_2" class="content px-3">
              <h1>Agent Name</h1>
              <h2>Agent Title</h2>
              <h3>Agent Phone</h3>
              <h4>Agent Email</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="agent_2" class="col-sm-4 p-0 mr-5 agent">
            <div class="agent-photo">
              <img src="img/agent.jpg">
            </div>
            <div id="content_2" class="content px-3">
              <h1>Agent Name</h1>
              <h2>Agent Title</h2>
              <h3>Agent Phone</h3>
              <h4>Agent Email</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Questions about optimizing code that works are better asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . This site focuses on code that isn't working as expected

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most simplified answer. It could be further simplified by creating an Agent "class". Definitely a better approach to look into.

**Side note:**

Look into using scoped variables (such as *let* or *const*) introduced with ES6. They're definitely the better way to go (rather than *var*), but you should make sure that the target browsers support them before using them in your code.

I wasn't sure if using *var* was an intentional choice or not, but I figured I'd mention it if you're new to JS.

```js
var container = document.querySelectorAll('#agent_1, #agent_2');
var content = document.querySelectorAll('#content_1, #content_2');

function inclusive(contentIndex, childIndex1, childIndex2) {
  return content[contentIndex].children[childIndex1].offsetHeight + 
    content[contentIndex].children[childIndex2].offsetHeight + 
    parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(content[contentIndex].children[childIndex1], null).getPropertyValue('margin-bottom')) + 
    parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(content[contentIndex].children[childIndex2], null).getPropertyValue('margin-bottom'));
}

function mouseOver(contentIndex, topInclusive, bottomInclusive) {
  return function() {
    content[contentIndex].style.maxHeight = (topInclusive + bottomInclusive) + 'px';
  }
}

function mouseOut(contentIndex, topInclusive) {
  return function() {
    content[contentIndex].style.maxHeight = topInclusive + 'px';
  }
}

// Agent 1
var topInclusiveA1 = inclusive(0, 0, 1);
var bottomInclusiveA1 = inclusive(0, 2, 3);
var mouseOverA1 = mouseOver(0, topInclusiveA1, bottomInclusiveA1);
var mouseOutA1 = mouseOut(0, topInclusiveA1);


// Agent 2 divs
var topInclusiveA2  = inclusive(1, 0, 1);
var bottomInclusiveA2 = inclusive(1, 2, 3);
var mouseOverA2 = mouseOver(1, topInclusiveA2, bottomInclusiveA2);
var mouseOutA2 = mouseOut(1, topInclusiveA2);

// Set Defaults
mouseOutA1();
mouseOutA2();

// Add event listeners
container[0].addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOverA1);
container[0].addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOutA1);
container[1].addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOverA2);
container[1].addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOutA2);
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid agent-bg">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row pt-5 pb-5">
   <div id="agent_1" class="col-sm-4 p-0 mr-5 agent">
    <div class="agent-photo">
     <img src="img/agent.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="content_2" class="content px-3">
     <h1>Agent Name</h1>
     <h2>Agent Title</h2>
     <h3>Agent Phone</h3>
     <h4>Agent Email</h4>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="agent_2" class="col-sm-4 p-0 mr-5 agent">
    <div class="agent-photo">
     <img src="img/agent.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="content_2" class="content px-3">
     <h1>Agent Name</h1>
     <h2>Agent Title</h2>
     <h3>Agent Phone</h3>
     <h4>Agent Email</h4>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```